# Grouping and finding max using awk

Tags: awk

The data needs to be grouped, each group having 6 values, and then needs to find the max in each group.

data:

```
0.0759313
0.0761037
0.0740772
0.0736791
0.0719802
0.0715406
0.0828038
0.0826728
0.0802384
0.0798476
0.0785342
0.0777939
0.0738756
0.0733486
0.0709046
0.0707067
0
0
```

Used this awk statements, but am not getting any result.

```
awk '{for(x=i+1;(x<=(i+5))&&(x<=NF);x++){a[++y]=$x;if(x==(i+5)){c=asort(a);b[z++]=a[c];i=i+6;y=0}}}END{for(j in b) print b[j]}'
```

Comment: i would recommend you to make an awk script file (multiple lines) for this task. this makes your code much more readable, which is good for you yourself and us, trying to understand the code and help. you will probably feel more free to change/add things, and be able to fix it yourself. if not, just put the code here again (edit your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
awk 'NR % 6 == 1 || $0 > max { max = $0 } NR % 6 == 0 { print max }' file
```

Always set `max` to the first value in each group of six, or if the value is greater than the current maximum. At the end of each group, print the value.

You may also want to include some additional logic to deal with printing the maximum of the last few numbers, in case the number of lines is not exactly divisible by 6:

```
END { if (NR % 6 != 0) print max }
```